# activeadmin custom filter that contains 2 words on the same attribute

Tags: activeadmin, ransack

I am using Rails 4.2 with activeadmin 1.0.0.pre1 and postgresql 9.3.

My model attribute is a string.

Right now if I filter for "invoice 2011" it will give me results that contain "invoice 2011", which is the default behavior if you select "contains". I want results that either contain "invoice" or "2011" in my case.

I know there is a `cont_any` chain method on ransack. This is what I am trying to achieve in a filter:

`Model.search(attribute_cont_any: %w(invoice 2011))`

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution at the moment, but maybe this will help you.

You can use the `cont_any` filter by doing this:

```
filter :attribute, filters: [:cont_any] # or [:start, :cont_any, ...]
```

But there are some problems at the moment:

1. That produces a url like: `?q[attribute_cont_any]=invoice+2011`, but it need's to be `?q[attribute_cont_any][]=invoice&q[attribute_cont_any][]=2011`.

   1. Maybe you can write a Javascript that will manipulate the form to split the one input into two.
   2. Or you can write a `before_action` which splits the params
      `params[:attribute_cont_any] = params[:attribute_cont_any].split`
2. If you request the correct URL `?q[attribute_cont_any][]=invoice&q[attribute_cont_any][]=2011`, it will return the right result, but the value of the filter input is now `["invoice", "2011"]

   This can maybe fixed by placing a `join` in the ActiveAdmin code